# Could we please have the 'noise' close reason on stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request, noise-reduction

I submit that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932407/what-superhero-would-your-language-of-choice-be) would justify it.

Comment: Sure wish I had the power of delete on SO for that one.

Answer (score 5):

It's a 'fun' question.

It's also annoying to have the site taken over by these. With more of these you have people spending their votes on them (and not spending their votes on programming questions), so they necessarily detract from the usefulness of the site.

Voting to close.

Comment: Not all fun questions are necessarily noise, although probably more than half.

Comment: I think people ask these types of questions purely to attempt gold badges.  If the *fun* question becomes popular, it's easy enough to gain the Famous Question badge and along the way you might even gain a Great Question or even a Stellar Question.  If you look at the highest voted questions, there are many tagged *fun*, so it's fairly obvious those questions encourage further *fun* questions.

Answer (score 1):

That question is off-topic.

However, you can always flag it as spam.

Comment: It's certainly not commercial spam.  People seem to be using whatever tool they have to close questions they don't like

Comment: @Andomar I take a more loose interpretation of the word `Spam`.

Comment: Google the definition of `spam`; it's sending unsolicited bulk messages indiscriminately with the objective of advertising a commercial product. I would say flagging as Spam questions that are clearly not spam by the "normal" definition is an abuse of the system.

Comment: @Kop - I would suggest that "indiscriminate" is the functional word, in this context. Spam is posting a message for reasons other than addressing the current thread... indiscriminate posting. A (non-commercial) *"come see my blog"* post is as much spam as a *"buy my product"* post, if its not an organic part of the thread.

Answer (score -4):

I actually voted to reopen that question, so it's been through a close cycle already.

It's definitely programming related and could provide potentially insightful analogies.  Maybe the superhero's could be on their respective tags for April 1st :)

Comment: I see nothing insightful in there so far.  That's the problem with these questions - they all have the *potential* to produce something interesting - hell, even a question that says *"post whatever's on your mind right now"* has the *potential* to produce something interesting - but because they're so wide-open and with such a low barrier to entry, most of what you get is just junk, and the votes are a popularity contest.  Even if there turn out to be good answers later on, the question is still noise.

Comment: @Aarobot: StackOverflow is really becoming the place that hates fun

Comment: @Andomar: This is an old debate, and the official outcome of that was that the deciding factor is "can I learn something from this?"  This probably sounds lame, but - *edutainment* is OK, *entertainment* is not.

Comment: @Andomar Stack Overflow doesn't "hate fun," it loves productivity.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: If you hate fun, you also throw productivity out of the window.  See http://37signals.com/svn/archives2/the_false_fight_between_fun_and_business.php

Comment: @Andomar: That's why we don't hate fun.  Fun questions can still be productive/educational.  But certain fun questions are [just procrastination](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/procrastination-and-the-bikeshed-effect.html).

Comment: Sigh. The argument is always "you guys hate fun". Or the ever-popular "You guys just like closing stuff because it makes you feel powerful", but I think "you guys hate fun" is even stupider

Comment: @Aarobot: So what was the last fun question that got through?

Comment: @Andomar: Code golf questions get through all the time.  The `fun` tag shows several more within the past few months.  But even if a search turned up nothing, the more important question would be: What fun questions have been submitted that are genuinely useful and not just noise?  Asking a good "fun" question is incredibly hard; you have to put it together in such a way that people leave useful answers as opposed to joke answers or off-the-cuff remarks.  If you can show me one that's closed and meets those criteria, I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @Aarobot: Let's assume for a second that super hero question had taken off.  The next time I was coding Flash I could think of the Flash superhero.  That would connect whole new regions of my mind and lead to insights and creativity.  It's these cross associations that tend to get me through a mental block

Comment: @Andomar: *Any* topic at all could "connect whole new regions of your mind and lead to insights and creativity".  That's like the snake-oil supplements claiming to "boost your immune system and promote better health." I think the value needs to be a bit more tangible than that in order to meet the bar. I'm not saying that the issue is entirely black-and-white, but we have to draw the line *somewhere*, and this is *way* on the far side.

Comment: @Aarobot: With bar is effectively at 5 people who think something is not funny/interesting/useful, the line is drawn a bit too far away from fun questions

Comment: @Andomar The "five people" bar works exceptionally well across the rest of the site. If you feel your question is different, and requires different attention, then it probably doesn't fit well on Stack Overflow.